# Stock Status Indexing In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

While Stock Status index is processing,some of the products' stock_status field in cataloginventory_stock_status table becomes 0. Why is it happening.?

Any Observer event available for after reindex process for stock status in Magento 1.9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this observer event "after_reindex_process_cataloginventory_stock" for my problem, it solved my problem.

```
<after_reindex_process_cataloginventory_stock>
    <observers>
        <namespace_modulename>
            <class>namespace_modulename/observertwo</class>
            <method>stockStatusChange</method>
        </namespace_modulename>
    </observers>
</after_reindex_process_cataloginventory_stock>
```

I wrote update query in "stockStatusChange" function,It worked perfectly.
observertwo.php file

```
public function stockStatusChange($observer)
{
   $connectionWrite = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection ('core_write');
   $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_status SET stock_status = 1 WHERE 
   stock_status = 0";
   $connectionWrite->query($sqlUpdate);
}
```